# Route53 Healthcheck integration with Cloudwatch Alarm Using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am unable to integrate Route53 HealthCheck with Cloudwatch Alarms using Terraform.
I've tried "HealthCheckId" in cloudwatch Alarms and also "cloudwatch-alarm-name" in Healthcheck section. Neither seemed to work. Everything is getting created by the integration isn't working.
Here's my code :

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "route53-healthcheck-sns" {
  name      = "route53-healthcheck"
  provider  = "aws.oregon"

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws sns subscribe --topic-arn ${self.arn} --region us-west-2 --protocol email --notification-endpoint ${var.emails}"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_health_check" "r53_healthcheck" {
  fqdn              = "my.domain.com"
  port              = 443
  type              = "HTTPS"
  resource_path     = "/SalesPortal/#!/"
  failure_threshold = "3"
  request_interval  = "30"
  measure_latency   = "1"
  tags = {
    Name = "r53_healthcheck"
   }
}


resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "route53-healthcheck-alarm" {
  alarm_name = "r53-alarm"
  comparison_operator = "LessThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods = "2"
  metric_name = "HealthCheckStatus"
  namespace = "AWS/Route53"
  period = "60"
  statistic = "Minimum"
  threshold = "0"
  alarm_description = "This metric monitor whether the server is down or not."
  insufficient_data_actions = []
  actions = ["${aws_sns_topic.route53-healthcheck-sns.arn}"]
  dimensions {
    HealthCheckId           = "${aws_route53_health_check.r53_healthcheck.id}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a little more detail to your question about what exactly "isn't working" about it? You mentioned that the Terraform run succeeds, but not what you tried after that, what you expected, and what actually happened. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Martin, The script gets executed, all the resources are created as well, but Route53HealthCheck is not connected to the alarm created.

Comment: Please add that additional information to your question! (It's normal practice to edit questions on Stack Overflow to improve them with additional context.) It would be most helpful to show exactly what you ran or looked at to decide that the check and the alarm were not created, so the reader can see exactly what seems to be missing and thus how that is likely to relate to the configuration you shared.

Comment: This is exactly what I used Martin.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure it out, @ShowmikBose?

Comment: Also I think the snippet is missing the alarm resource itself.

Comment: @trallnag -  HealthCheckId           = "${aws_route53_health_check.r53_healthcheck.id}" This wasn't working. Been a few years now I don't really recall fixing it. We had taken another approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Route 53 Health check service is only available in us-east-1. The issue is addressed here: https://medium.com/@fmaree/working-with-aws-r53-health-checks-and-terraform-70d79b56a1dd